# How do I press the key by using python

Tags: python

I am trying to make this project(https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/637040443/) in python. I found out how to copy the text, but pasting doesn't work. So I am trying to make python to press Ctrl+V and press enter. How do I press Ctrl and V at same time and then press Enter?

Comment: Please don't link other sites (especially those that require Javascript to run) as necessary parts of the question. A question should be self-contained and should only use links to convey auxiliary information. Aside from that, are you using a GUI framework in Python, such as Tkinter? If so, which one? If not, then you need to pick one since "Ctrl+V" is meaningless to a Python command line application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [`pyautogui.hotkey()`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-hotkey-function) and the [`pyautogui.press()`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-press-keydown-and-keyup-functions) methods:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```